# Use an editable Qt resource

Tags: c++, qt, qresource

I'm working on a syntax highlighter getting styles to apply from an xml file.

I wanted to add this file in the qrc but I would like this file to be editable by the user.

How to get the benefit of the qrc to avoid path management from the exe ?

Comment: I think you can load and edit resources at runtime, but AFAIK there's no way to save them back in the executable file.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to manage paths properly with QResource ?

Comment: I think [`QSettings`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) might be more appropriate here.  Perhaps load the default value(s) from bound resources and save the edited values on a per-user base via `QSettings`.

Comment: Another possibility could be to use QResource directly, and register resources you would like. Not checked, though, but it might be possible to set resources you like at run-time. More information can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qresource.html#registerResource . Of course, you would still have to introduce your resources in some way. But maybe through management of them as files, and registering/unregistering them you would be able to achieve that users would be able to edit them at run-time?